# Bmw N52N Lambda probes madness

Tags: bmw, o2-sensor, gasoline, obd, lambda

Owner of a BMW E60 523i LCI Automatic (N52N engine. aka N52k). 105000 Kms on the clock.
The error codes below after deletion, re-appear after 300~400 Kms.
It is theoritically impossible for 4 lambda probes to die in the same time.

[image]

I logged some OBD values during a 33kms trip which I graphed in 2 parts:

- Trip part 1: https://plot.ly/~harakiri/22/#/
- Trip Part 2: https://plot.ly/~harakiri/25/#/plot

You can click on a legend item to show/hide it.

The symptoms are a very high fuel consumption:
 - 17L/100km in city.
 - 9L/100km in highway.

I can't really spot abnormalities by comparing the graphs.
Fuel Trims tend to be somehow funcky but that wouldn't explain the extreme high fuel consumption.

AFR and Lambda voltages sound somehow correct.

Idle is very smooth.

Thanks for your help